# Pandas equivalent to data.table

Tags: python, pandas

With `R`'s *`data.table`*, you can perform an operation on a column by group that returns a vector with arbitrary length.

Suppose, I'd like to gather the top 5 values of one column, grouped by another. *`data.table`* takes care of gluing the subgroups together.

```
require(magrittr)
library(data.table)

n <- 100
DT <- data.table(A = rnorm(n), B = sample(letters[1:4], n, replace = TRUE))
DT[, sort(B, decreasing = TRUE) %>% head(5), by = B]
```

With `Python` and *`pandas`*, I tried different strategies:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(n), 
                   'B' : [random.choice(list('abc')) for i in range(n)]})
# first try : 
groups = df.groupby('B')
groups.apply(lambda x : sorted(x['A'], reverse=False)[:5])
```

but this solution gives back a 3x1 (assuming I have 3 groups) DataFrame with lists inside the rows, which does not appear weird though, as sorted will give back a list object.

```
# second try:
groups.apply(lambda x : np.sort(x['A'])[-5:])
```

is no more conclusive.

The solution I found, but looks really verbose to me, imply iterating the groups:

```
dfs = []
for g in groups:
    dfs.append(g[1].sort_values('A').tail(5))
pd.concat(dfs).sort_values('B')
```

Any idea of what I could use as a more elegant way to perform this operation ?
Thanks, I keep on searching for a Pythonic solution...

Comment: How is `df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='A', ascending=False).head(5))`?

Comment: Fwiw, more standard R code would be `DT[order(-A), head(.SD, 5), by = B]`

Comment: That's helpful, indeed. Good point !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(n), 
                   'B' : [np.random.choice(list('abc')) for i in range(n)]})
groups = df.groupby('B')
groups.apply(lambda x : x['A'].sort_values().tail(5))
```

Output:

```
B    
a  97    1.068696
   26    1.142186
   35    1.222854
   18    1.379540
   43    1.466977
b  46    1.185664
   94    1.206992
   49    1.464562
   81    1.609808
   51    1.814868
c  50    1.129484
   8     1.155544
   95    1.250349
   9     1.337286
   90    1.581751
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That definitely solve the issue. Thanx you and Abou's comment !

Comment: For a completely identical output to data.table i would need to store this result in a variable, reset_index and del the column 'level_1' (with the row index of the top values) which is added ... Am I correct ?